# Json convert DataFrame

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a Jston dict type data like the following:

```
{'statusCode': 200,
 'body': {'lambdaData': {'20210302': {'004565': 33010.29666478985,
    '002780': 119.79041526659631,
    '043200': 494.0269995476475, 
    '273140': 41.252622294271745,
    ...},
   'returnType': 'PAYLOAD'},
  'returnType': 'PAYLOAD'}}
```

I want to change like(pandas dataframe):

```
yyyymmdd stock_code  rate
20210302 004565      33010.29666478985
20210302 002780      119.79041526659631
20210303 004565      32010.29666478985
20210302 002780      219.79041526659631
```

thank you

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are getting the input in Jsons, that is dicts in Python.

I have written some loops to iterate through, maybe there is a more elegant way, but I would do in this way for better understanding of the code.

```
#import
import pandas as pd
#given json/dict in a variable
testData = { 'statusCode': 200, 'body': { 'lambdaData': { '20210302': { '004565': 33010.29666478985, '002780': 119.79041526659631, '043200': 494.0269995476475, '273140': 41.252622294271745 }, 'returnType': 'PAYLOAD' }, 'returnType': 'PAYLOAD' } }
#new empty dataframe with desired column names
Mydataframe = pd.DataFrame({'yyyymmdd': [], 'stock_code': [], 'rate': []})
#iterating through input json/dict
for key, value in testData.items():
    #if we found body which is again a dict
    if isinstance(value, dict) and key == 'body':
        #iterating through body
        for subDataKey, subDataValue in value.items():
            #if we found lambdaData which is again a dict
            if isinstance(subDataValue, dict) and subDataKey == 'lambdaData':
                #iterating through lambdaData
                for lambDataKey, lambDataValue in subDataValue.items():
                    #checking for dicts present in the lambdaData
                    if isinstance(lambDataValue, dict):
                        #iterating through that dict
                        for lambDataSubKey, lambDataSubValue in lambDataValue.items():
                            #saving values in the df
                            Mydataframe = Mydataframe.append([{'yyyymmdd':lambDataKey, 'stock_code':lambDataSubKey, 'rate':lambDataSubValue}], ignore_index=True)
```

Which will give below df as answer:

```
   yyyymmdd stock_code          rate
0  20210302     004565  33010.296665
1  20210302     002780    119.790415
2  20210302     043200    494.027000
3  20210302     273140     41.252622
```

*All the code lines have comments for the understanding.*